# Convergence in topology

Tags: general-topology

There is a sequence=(1,1,1,1,.....)
                                   x2=(0,1/2,1/2,1/2,...)
                                   x3=(0,0,1/3,1/3,....) and so on.
simply it converges in Product topology.The uniform metric is not bounded so it is not convergent in uniform topology.So I believe it is not convergent in box topology as it is not convergent in uniform topology.But I see that all the open neighbourhood containing (0,0,0,0,.....) contains all the terms except those starting finite terms ie. convergent in box topology.What have I missed? Am I said something which is conceptually wrong!

Comment: "The uniform metric is not bounded" what? How is this relevant? The uniform distance from 0 is just the supremum of the entries' absolute values, and so we should be able to see what happens uniformly in this case without much trouble. In the box topology, it's not true that every neighborhood of 0 contains all but finitely many terms of this sequence.

Comment: Kevin please give me an example of two points whose uniform distance is unbounded to my idea clear.Probably my idea to calculate this distance is wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. There's no such thing, in a metric space, as two points whose distance is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

The basis elements of the uniform topology are sets that look like this:

$U=B(x_1, \epsilon) \times B(x_2, \epsilon) \times B(x_3, \epsilon) \times \ldots$.

In particular the $\epsilon$ value is fixed.

On the other hand, the basis elements of the box topology are sets that look like this:

$V = B(x_1, \epsilon_1) \times B(x_2, \epsilon_2) \times B(x_3, \epsilon_3) \times \ldots$.

Now the $\epsilon$ value varies at each coordinate.

To show $x_n$ non-convergent in the box topology, you need to choose the sequence $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \ldots$ so it decreases quickly enough to make $V$ exclude all of $x_1,x_2,\ldots $ .

How quickly it needs to decrease I leave that up to you!

Answer (score 0):

$(x_n)_n \rightarrow x, n \to \infty$ in the product topology iff for each coordinate $k$, we have that $(x_n)_k \rightarrow x_k, n \to \infty$.

In "your" sequence (or Munkres' really IIRC) for a fixed coordinate $k$ your sequence is just $0, 0,\dots, 0 $ ($k-1$ many times), ${1 \over n}, {1 \over (n+1)} \ldots$ which indeed tends to $0$.

In the uniform metric we just have to compute $d(x_n, 0)$ where $d$ is the uniform metric. $d(x_n, 0) =\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as is easily computed so $(x_n)$ does converge to the $0$-sequence in the uniform metric.

The set $O = (-1,1) \times (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \times (-\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}) \ldots = \prod_n U_n$ where $U_n = (-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ in the box topology, that contains *no* point $x_n$. So no convergence in that topology.

Comment: To check the convergence in uniform topology we are see ....Does the uniform metric tends to 0?Is it  the procedure @Henno Brandsma